# Custom title for existing Dexterity content type

Tags: plone, dexterity

I have a Plone site using a local product which is common across several of our projects that provides a Dexterity content type which is entitled "Generic". I'm using it in a somewhat different way, however, so I'd like the content type to appear as "Specific" in the add content menu. (It's not necessary for the add/edit path to contain the adjusted type name.) Is there a programmatic way I can change the title for my installed version of the type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best approach, but I've added an importStep that does:

```
portal_types['common.package.ContentTypeID'].title = 'Specific'
```